# Draw route between two points in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue2-google-maps

Code below working fine and draws a `polyline` between two points, but what I need is path, so searching how to draw route between these points instead of polyline using **vue2-google-maps** package?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Start</h2>
      <label>
        <gmap-autocomplete @place_changed="setStartPlace"></gmap-autocomplete>
        <button @click="addMarker">Add</button>
      </label>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>End</h2>
      <label>
        <gmap-autocomplete @place_changed="setEndPlace"></gmap-autocomplete>
        <button @click="addMarker">Add</button>
      </label>
      <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <gmap-map ref="xyz" :center="center" :zoom="4" style="width:100%;  height: 400px;">
      <gmap-marker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :position="m.position"
        @click="center=m.position"
      ></gmap-marker>
      <gmap-polyline v-bind:path.sync="path" v-bind:options="{ strokeColor:'#008000'}"></gmap-polyline>
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  data() {
    return {
      // default to Montreal to keep it simple
      // change this to whatever makes sense
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
      markers: [],
      places: [],
      path: [],
      currentPlace: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.geolocate();
  },

  methods: {
    // receives a place object via the autocomplete component
    setStartPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
    },
    setEndPlace(place) {
      this.currentPlace = place;
    },
    addMarker() {
      if (this.currentPlace) {
        const marker = {
          lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
          lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng()
        };
        this.path.push(marker);
        this.markers.push({ position: marker });
        this.places.push(this.currentPlace);
        this.center = marker;
        this.currentPlace = null;
      }
    },
    geolocate: function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.center = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have updates for this?

Answer (score 7):

By "*Draw route between two points*", I assume you mean to use this [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview).

You can create your own component by using `vue2-google-maps` factory method. See more [Adding your own components](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps#adding-your-own-components).

Example code:

```js
import { MapElementFactory } from "vue2-google-maps";

export default MapElementFactory({
  name: "directionsRenderer",

  ctr() {
    return google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  },

  events: [],

  mappedProps: {},

  props: {
    origin: { type: Object },
    destination: { type: Object },
    travelMode: { type: String }
  },

  afterCreate(directionsRenderer) {
    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    this.$watch(
      () => [this.origin, this.destination, this.travelMode],
      () => {
        let { origin, destination, travelMode } = this;
        if (!origin || !destination || !travelMode) return;

        directionsService.route(
          {
            origin,
            destination,
            travelMode
          },
          (response, status) => {
            if (status !== "OK") return;
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
});
```

And then use it:

```html
<GmapMap
  :zoom="7"
  :center="{ lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }">
  <DirectionsRenderer
    travelMode="DRIVING"
    :origin="origin"
    :destination="destionation"/>
</GmapMap>
```

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sun-qnxo6)

Comment: How to clear the drawn route with a button maybe ?

Comment: It draw a poly line between start and end, but with default red marker, ignore my custom marker created.